# Unit testing communication between siblings in Angular 2

Tags: angular, unit-testing, components, testbed

How does someone test communication between 2 sibling components in Angular 2? I don't seem to find any viable resource online.

app.component.html

```
<comp1 #a></comp1>
<comp2 [x]="a.get()"></comp2>
```

where `get()` is a function within the `comp1` component whose value I'm passing to one of the class variables of component `comp2`. How can I test this efficiently?

`app.component` is the parent component of `comp1` and `comp2` and encloses them.

Comment: There are a bunch of explanation about that on the web, plrese refer to Angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/testing#test-a-component. You write in your case the test in `app.component.spec.ts`.

Comment: I'm not asking how to write tests. Also, there is no doc which explains how to test the communication I'm trying to imply here. Believe me. I've searched everywhere.

Comment: This is a straight forward test actually. Have you even tried? Post your test here so I can continue helping you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet you've mentioned gives a partial idea. But I think you want to test if changes in one component's data affects the other component's data.

```
it('should xx', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const child1 = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(ChildComponent1))[0];
    const but = child1.queryAll(By.css('#some_element'))[0].nativeElement; // change data in child1
    fixture.detectChanges(); // detect changes

    const child2 = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(ChildComponent2))[0];
    const child2info = child2.queryAll(By.css('some_element'))[1].nativeElement.innerHTML;
    expect(child2info).toBe('some_data'); // check if reflected in child2
  }));
```

So, basically you use `By.directive()` to fetch the DOM elements for a child component. Once you've done that, you need to edit the DOM using `nativeElement`.

After editing, use `By.directive()` again to fetch the DOM elements for the second child component and then further check its DOM for data changes.

Note:
For changing the data in `ChildComponent1`, do something like `but.value = "something"` (if its an `<input>` box) and then create an `Event` before you call `detectChanges()`.